# Couchbase convert epoch to ISO

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm struggling to convert Epoch to ISO datetime with **Couchbase N1QL**. Couchbase stores etoch time with milliseconds and I need full ISO8 format YYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.S. I have tried:

```
SELECT  DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'year'), DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'month'), DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'day')
```

but it obviously returns json-like response. I tries to concatenate like  `SELECT  DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'year') || DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'month') || DATE_PART_MILLIS(146328474000`0, 'day')

But it renders nothing back

```
[
  {
    "$1": null
  }
]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Couchbase you can store the time as number (In Milliseconds) 
or string as ISO-8601 format. It provides many date functions to work on
ISO-8601 format as described at 
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html

```
SELECT MILLIS_TO_STR(1463284740000);
```

DATE_PART_MILLIS(date1, part [, tz])
Extracts the value of a given date component from an Epoch/UNIX timestamp value.
Return Value -- An integer representing the value of the component extracted from the timestamp.
String concatenation expects string, Add TOSTRING around the function like

```
SELECT  TOSTRING(DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'year')) || "-" ||
        TOSTRING(DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'month')) || "-" || 
        TO_STRING(DATE_PART_MILLIS(1463284740000, 'day'));
```